# Equals (=) and Not Equals (<>) in kdb+ 'if' condition with temporal values

Tags: kdb

Given the following variables:

```
x: (5 xbar `minute$.z.T);
y: (1 xbar `minute$.z.T);
```

This `if` condition is evaluated correctly:
`if[x=y;...];`

However, what confuses me is that this will **not** evaluate correctly, and throw an `nyi`: `if[x<>y;...]`

When running `x=y` and `x<>y` on their own (outside the `if` condition), they evaluate to either `0b` or `1b`.

Why does `<>` result in an `nyi` when used in an `if` condition?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not certain what the problem with your code is. I just launched a new q session and filled in everything as you described with a simple if expression:

```
x: (5 xbar `minute$.z.T);
y: (1 xbar `minute$.z.T);
if[x<>y; show 123]
```

x was 17:05 and y was 17:07, so the above expression evaluated to true and printed 123 to the console. Perhaps the issue is actually some error within your expression you want evaluated and not the condition itself?

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer suggests, the x<>y is not the cause of the nyi error, it is the logic within your if statement you need to check. If it works outside the if statement it will work inside it.

The reason you think x=y works inside the if statement, but x<>y does not, is your x and y are not equal, so the if statement is only executed in the x<>y case. When you test x=y,  further statements will not be run within the if statement, hence you do not see the nyi error.

If you share the rest of the code we could help with that the problem may be, an example of an nyi error is using the colon for return functionality, when not inside a function, eg,

```
if[x=y;:5] /no error thrown as :5 is not executed
if[x<>y;:5] / throws nyi as x<>y, and :5 is not implemented outside of lambdas
```